C2672 '_Sort_unchecked': no matching overloaded function found GA error finding this error in my class sorting usding #include <algorithm>
The thing I am doing is making a Growable Array class in c++ and am using templates for it and in this implementation I have also a subclass iterator //forward olny and then in the main this line is giving an errorsort(Aint.begin(), Aint.end()); mentioned in Title.
// My header file

#pragma once
template<typename T>
class GA
{
    int size;
    T* Vs;
public:
    GA(int _size = 1)
    {
        size = _size;
        Vs = new T[size]{};
    }
    // suggestion by PaulMcKenzie but still the error remains
    GA(const GA& other)
    {
        size = other.size;
        Vs = new T[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            Vs[i] = other.Vs[i];
        }
    }
    T& operator[](int i)
    {
        return Vs[i];
    }
    int length()
    {
        return size;
    }
    const T& operator[](int i)const
    {
        return Vs[i];
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const GA<T>& G)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < G.size; i++)
        {
            cout << G[i] << " ";
        }
        return cout;
    }
    void push_back(T v)
    {
        T* HA = new T[size + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            HA[i] = Vs[i];
        HA[size] = v;
        delete[] Vs;
        Vs = HA; size++;
    }
    ~GA()
    {
        delete[]Vs;
    }

    class iterator
    {
        T* p;
        friend class GA;

        iterator(T* _p)
        {
            p = _p;
        }

    public:
        /* Yksisarvinen suggested this and I tried but still got the same error I hope I did it correctly*/ 
        T& operator->()
        {
             return *p;
        }
        int operator - (const iterator& s) const
        {
            return s.p - this->p;
        }
        bool operator == (const iterator& s)
        {
            return this->p == s.p;
        }
        bool operator != (const iterator& s)
        {
            return this->p != s.p;
        }
        const iterator operator++(int)
        {
            iterator temp = *this;
            this->p++;
            return temp;
        }
        iterator& operator++()
        {
            this->p++;
            return *this;
        }
        T& operator*()
        {
            return *p;
        }
    };


    iterator begin()
    {
        return iterator(Vs);
    }
    iterator end()
    {
        return iterator(Vs + size);
    }

    iterator find(T v)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (Vs[i] == v)
                return iterator(Vs + i);
        }
        return end();
    }

    void replaceAt(iterator& i, T v)
    {
        *i = v;
    }
    void insertBefore(iterator& t, T v)
    {
        T* HA = new T[size + 1];
        for (int vi = 0, hi = 0; vi < size; vi++, hi++)
        {
            if (&Vs[vi] == t.p)
            {
                HA[hi] = v;
                hi++;
            }
            HA[hi] = Vs[vi];
        }

        delete[]Vs;
        Vs = HA;
        size++;
    }
};

//main()

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
#include "GA.h"

void initAint(GA<int>& Aint)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Aint.length(); i++)
    {
        Aint[i] = (rand() % 6 + 1) * 100;
    }
}
void print(const char* msg, const GA<int>& Aint)
{
    cout << msg << " : {";
    cout << Aint << "}" << endl;
}
int main()
{
    GA<int> Aint(10);
    initAint(Aint);
    print("Aint [] ", Aint);

    /*
    for (GA<int>::iterator i = Aint.begin(); i != Aint.end(); i++)
    {
    // (*i).do something to the i'th value'
    cout << *i << " ";
    }
    */

    auto fi = Aint.find(500);
    if (fi == Aint.end())
    {
        cout << "500 not found..." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "500 is found..." << endl;
        (*fi) /= 100;

        Aint.insertBefore(fi, 1000);
    }
    print("\n\n\nmodified Aint [] ", Aint);

    sort(Aint.begin(), Aint.end());
    print("\n\n\nSorted Aint [] ", Aint);


    /*for (auto ri = Aint.rbegin(); ri != Aint.rend(); ri++)
    {
        cout << *ri;
    }*/

    return 0;
}


can you help me resove this problem

std::sort requires RandomAccessIterator, GA<T>::iterator is not RandomAccessIterator, it's hardly even a ForwardIterator (missing operator-> and required typedefs).

The thing I am doing is making a Growable Array class in c++ -- Why do this when std::vector exists (and has officially existed in C++ for 26 years now).

I know vectors are avalible I am trying to make it to understand c++ better as I'm still new to it

@MHamzaNaveed I am trying to make it to understand c++ better -- Before you even consider writing iterator classes, you should address the really outstanding issues that is fundamental to writing classes in C++ correctly, such as the rule of 3.  This simple program int main() { GA<int> v1(10); GA<int> v2 = v1; } has a double-free error.  Go to the Managing resources section of that link, and you will see a class there that has the same issues as your code does now.

So I think you are telling me to make a copy constructor ok I'll add that as well and see if that resolves my issue , So I added that and the error still remains

@MHamzaNaveed So I added that and the error still remains -- Note that the comment section is for comments, not answers.  My comment is directed towards writing iterator classes for classes that are fundamentally flawed to begin with.

Also, did you read the comment by @Yksisarvinen, and thus implement all of the things you see in the first column (Expression) here?  If you cannot take an iterator that you created and be able to fulfill all of those functions you see, then it isn't a random access iterator.
